# Apache mod_rewrite fake pushState directory mapping

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, pushstate, url-mapping

If have played around a lot with mod_rewrite rules in my httpd.conf file. Regardless of my research i haven't been able to get a couple of things working.

This is my file structure:

```
/
-index.php
-app.php
    /css
    -style.css
    /js
    -script.js
```

The server should either serve the index.php (home page) or app.php (single application page). Both the script and style files are included in both php files.

**Goals**

- My domain *domain.com* should serve the **index.php**, the address bar should show *www.domain.com*

*(This seems to work already, per default.)*

- The subdomain *domain.com/a* should be changed to *domain.com/a/* if necessary. This domain should serve the **app.php** file.

*(This is already working to an extend. One problem is that the relative links inside app.php are wrong, because the file "thinks" it is in a subdirectory instead of root. This I would like to change)*

- Anything after *domain.com/a/* e.g. *domain.com/a/user/10* should stay in the address bar and serve the **app.php** as usual. Ideally, to preserve relative links again, the file should "know" it is in the root folder.

*(This is in order to support a "fake" pushState server) **EDIT** Clarification: Everything after the /a/ will be interpreted by my Javascript app. When the client clicks a link like domain.com/a/user/10 there will be no extra request to the server.*

**Bonus**

- Add trailing slashes to all URLs except the root url.

  e.g. turn *domain.com/a/user/10* into *domain.com/a/user/10/*
- Add www to URL in case it is missing.

**What I've tried**

-add www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

-add slashes

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

-redirect /a/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/a/)$
RewriteRule ^ /app.php
```

Any pointers or help are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**Edit**

I have used this tool http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test some conditions.